# In Active Directory, if there's two way trust between domains, do both domains have access to the resources in each other's domains?

Tags: active-directory, domain, trust

Since the trust allows authentication of domain to domain will the Domain Admins of each Domain be able to manage each others Domains?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to add resources in the appropriate security groups.  You will need to add opposing admins in to the opposing \users\Administrators groups.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fa4070bd-b09f-4ad2-b628-2624030c0116/forest-trust-domain-admins-to-manage-both-domains?forum=winserverDS